# How does the composite (primary) keys should work as foreign key in Sync Framework?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

i'm currently working on re-designing my database to work with Sync Framework. Based on the articles i've read so far, my primary key which is an identity type would cause collision on Sync. Therefore, i decided to add a column called ClientId (int type), so that i can make that new column and my existing primary key column as a composite primary key.

This ClientId would be use to identify which client/node is the source of data, thus resolving data collision issue during the sync. However, I'm quite confused on how i will restructure my tables when referencing a composite foreign keys and I will also need the client id on the referencing table. Here's the sample layout (this is one-to-many):

**Assessment Table (Main transactional table):**

- AssessmentId (PK, identity, int)
- Description (varchar)
- AssessedValue (decimal)

**Adjustments Table (intermediate, transactional table)**

- AdjustmentId (PK, identity, int)
- AssessmentId (FK, int)
- AdjustmentDescription (varchar)

Here's what i did when implemented the composite keys:

**Assessment Table (Main transactional table):**

- AssessmentId (composite, PK, identity, int)
- ClientId (composite PK, int)
- Description (varchar)
- AssessedValue (decimal)

**Adjustments Table (intermediate, transactional table)**

- AdjustmentId (composite PK, identity, int)
- ClientId (composite PK, FK, int) - its an FK referencing to Assessment table,
  and at the same time part of composite PK on this table.. im utilizing the ClientId here
- AssessmentId (FK, int)
- AdjustmentDescription (varchar)

Am i doing this correctly? Or should i create another ClientId for Adjustment table as its own composite keys, then create a column for the FK ClientId of the Assessment table?

Thanks for the help (and sorry for the bad confusing english)!

Currently using: SQL Server 2008 R2 
Sync Framework: ver 2.1

Comment: looks good to me. btw, regardless of whether you use Sync Fx or not, think of how you would design this if you are consolidating data in a central store.

Comment: @JuneT - Thanks for the comment, to be honest, this will be the first time that i will be using Sync Fx.. Basically i have a central data store, and the client will subscribe/upload data to it. I just wanted to make sure that its okay to utilize ids, if its not, i'll create separate client ids for each table.